# CSS module classes work on development, but are overridden on production

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

All the styles on my project are defined inside css modules, and only recently I noticed that, on the production build generated by Nextjs, some of them are overridden by other styles (this would only make sense if they were defined on the same module, which is not the case). This breaks my app on production, but everything seems to work just fine on development.

Here's an example:

```
///mobile.module.css
 .expandIcon {
    width: 12px;
}

///mobile.tsx
import React from "react";
import styles from "./mobile.module.css";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import OpenInFullRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/OpenInFullRounded";

const mobile: NextPage = () => {
  return <OpenInFullRoundedIcon className={styles.expandIcon} />
};

export default mobile;
```

Here's how this class is loaded on development:

[image]

And here's how it's overridden on prod:

[image]

And to make it worse, the class overriding mine is not even defined on my project.
I'm somewhat new to NextJs, so I would appreciate any insight on this issue.

Comment: Hi, Did you search for css-vubbuv classname in your project?

Comment: Hello, yes, I did. Couldn't find it in my project anywhere.
All I know is that css-vubbuv is added by a style tag to my DOM.

Comment: I had the same problem when I used ant design, and some global styles apply to my project maybe your problem is for the material-ui

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it lol
Turns out material ui's styles have precedence over custom styles, except inline styles, due to how custom styles are injected by Next. I will answer this question and link the source to this info in case it's useful to anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as pointed out by [ali.zabetpour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13566443/ali-zabetpour), the issue is related to how some external libraries's styles are prioritized over custom styles after building, in this case, Material ui/Mui.
Here is a link to Mui's docs that explains this in detail and offers a solution using  their StyledEngineProvider component, which solved my problem:
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order-3

Comment: Do you simply wrap this around the offending component or you need to do it at the layout level ? The example they provide is not clear on where it has to be applied.